# How to compare date with milliseconds with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datetime

I try to make a query to my database with LINQ to SQL.

example :

```
var t = from a in context.A where a.date == myDate select a;
```

The problem is the date from SQL was return with millisecond, myDate variable contain de good milliseconds, but when i compare the date together the comparaison is not valide because the default output of myDate is MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss and sql return MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff.

How i can get my date with the millisecond ?

Comment: édric: how are you building `myDate` - `DateTime.Parse()` or other?

Comment: @p.campbell No my date was a value from database, whoe was store in an object with  a date property

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you want to compare your .NET datetime with precision milliseconds to the SQL datetime with precision milliseconds.

On testing, it looks like the SQL generated by LINQ To SQL has a defect: it rounds from its internal storage of ticks to a string representation improperly.

I've submitted this to Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/589054  Try the repro!

To work around this defect where milliseconds in your `DateTime` are rounded improperly in the generated SQL, consider picking out each element of your date, and comparing each item (which is ridiculous, I know!):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse("Jan 1 2010 09:44:33.0110");

var t = m.Msgs.Where(mm => 
                mm.CreatedOn.Value.Date == d.Date
             && mm.CreatedOn.Value.Hour == d.Hour
             && mm.CreatedOn.Value.Minute== d.Minute
             && mm.CreatedOn.Value.Second == d.Second
             && mm.CreatedOn.Value.Millisecond == d.Millisecond);
```

Comment: One caveat: a `datetime` column has a precision of about 3ms, so the "date to find" could end up between representable dates. This is not a problem if that date is also read from a datetime column

Answer (score 5):

Is it the case that one of your dates has millisecond precision, and the other doesn't?
In that case, I would be inclined to try something like this:

```
var t = from a in context.A where SqlMethods.DateDiffSecond(a.date, myDate) == 0 select a;
```

This [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882657.aspx) shows the DateTime methods/properties that are supported by Linq to SQL.

Comment: This will give overflow in some servers

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this link on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40542286/1305969)

```
source = source.Where(o => 
  o.TaskStartDate.Value.AddTicks(-(o.TaskStartDate.Value.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)) == dtStartDate);
```

same problem as you are facing, I have got resolution in like 5 mins.

Comment: This solution doesn't work against a database because "'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddTicks(Int64)'".  p.campbell's solution works against the db.