# How to compare datetime (only dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt not whole fff section in datetime) in linq C#?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I want to compare datetime which comes from kendo filter in (DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss tt) format and wanted to compare with my database using linq expression.

```
IEnumerable<ValidateTaskSummaryDetails> source;
source = source.Where(o => o.TaskStartDate.Value == dtStartDate);
```

Here `dtStartDate` comes from Kendo, the date i have got from kendo is `'10/11/2016 15:34:45'` and the date in my database is `'10/11/2016:15:34:45'` but then also i have got error like `'Enumeration yielded no results'` I think it must take the whole lot of a date with `.fff` section also but I don't get that from kendo (i.e. I don't want to get it).

The problem here is When i tried to `compare both dates` which are identical,
But in comparison system compared with `'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss.fff tt'` now the problem is with `'.fff'` due to this dates are not compared and hence `yielded no result`.

Do any have any solution?.

Comment: Your `dtStartDate` isn't _already_ a `DateTime`? It doesn't (shouldn't) have any format. Format concept only applies when you get their _textual_ (aka string) representation. Also there is no `DD` and `YYYY` as a custom date specifiers. They are case sensitive. `dd` and `yyyy` specifiers are exist instead.

Comment: yes `dtStartDate` is already a `DateTime` but when i compare both the linq expression compare it by millisecond fraction also which turned out that dates are different and hence yielded no result while actually both `DateTime` are same if you remove the millisecond portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> both DateTime are same if you remove the millisecond portion.

If so, you can truncate the milliseconds part of your `TaskStartDate.Value` like;

```
source = source.Where(o => 
                      o.TaskStartDate.Value.AddTicks(-(o.TaskStartDate.Value.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)) 
                      == dtStartDate);
```

Comment: Superb even i have tried to reduce that portion using different method but it wasn't working, you saved my time thanks for the help :)

Comment: Hi although, this worked great, i have used this same technique in another page, it isn't working, and got the error like: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddTicks(Int64)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Answer (score 1):

When you perform equality comparison, you are right that compares the complete representation of `DateTime`, to be honest it compares the equality of `Ticks` property of each `DateTime` object.

```
public static bool operator ==(DateTime d1, DateTime d2) {
    return d1.InternalTicks == d2.InternalTicks;
}
```

(from [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,df6b1eba7461813b))

If you need the equality only of Date (year, month, day) and Time (hours, minute, seconds) you need to implement something like the following:

```
IEnumerable<ValidateTaskSummaryDetails> source;
source = source.Where(o => o.TaskStartDate.Value.Year == dtStartDate.Year && 
                        o.TaskStartDate.Value.Month == dtStartDate.Month && 
                        o.TaskStartDate.Value.Day == dtStartDate.Day &&
                        o.TaskStartDate.Value.Hour == dtStartDate.Hour &&
                        o.TaskStartDate.Value.Minute == dtStartDate.Minute &&
                        o.TaskStartDate.Value.Second == dtStartDate.Second);
```

Or comparing equality of string representation in required format.

```
var format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
source = source.Where(o => o.TaskStartDate.Value.ToString(format) == dtStartDate.ToString(format));
```

The first approach will be faster, because it requires to compare numeric fields instead of `string`. It should be noted (as it noted from comments) that converting `DateTime` to string and comparing it's string representation is a kind of bad idea and it is good example of bad smell code. It will give required results but you should avoid it - string comparison is always worse than numeric comparison.

It is recommended to avoid equality comparison of `DateTime` objects, because there are too much variables which affecting the result (Hour, Minute, Second, Day, Month, Year, Millisecond) and perform only inequality comparisons (<, <=, >, >=). Or compare only `Date` component of `DateTime` as following:

```
source = source.Where(o => o.TaskStartDate.Value.Date == dtStartDate.Date);
```

It is frequently enough for most common usages of this.

Comment: This is the simplest example, easy to understand thanks :)

Comment: Be careful, there is no `DD` and `YYYY` as a custom date specifiers. And comparing DateTime values with their string representations is _generally_ a bad idea.

Comment: @SonerGönül I copied format from question. I know that comparing string representations of DateTime is a bad idea, but AFAIK comparing the full equality of DateTime is a bad idea too.

Comment: updated answer with correct format and notes for comparing equality of strings.

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov Hi also, there is one question can you please suggest how to achieve the opposite result that means what if we don't want the date which comes in filter. (not equal to dtStartDate)

Comment: @HarshVyas Hi. Do you mean something like this? `d1.Year != d2.Year && d1.Month != d2.Month && d1.Day != d2.Day` or `d1.Date != d2.Date`.

Comment: Yes, `for example` if i want to get result `from db`, that pick all data `except` the one having `date = '23/11/2016 13:15:00'` so now if i compare d1.Year != 2016 then the condition is not working properly its not getting any data from db. if any suggestions that would be very great :)